# Failed to find Platform SDK with path: platforms;android-33

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I'm encountering an error while trying to build my Flutter project. The error message I'm receiving is:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Failed to find Platform SDK with path: platforms;android-33

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 16s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             19.0s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I have already tried updating my Flutter SDK and ensuring that the necessary Android SDK platform is installed. However, the issue persists. I'm not sure what else to try or how to resolve this error.

If anyone has encountered a similar issue or has any suggestions on how to resolve this error, I would greatly appreciate your assistance. Thank you!

Comment: In Android Studio open the `SDK manager` and scroll down to `Android 13.0 (Tiramisu)`  and enable the check box `Android SDK Platform 33`. Then close the dialog with the OK button. Then SDK manager will download the missing component.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was able to resolve the issue. Thanks for your Response.

Comment: When i tried installing Firebase, i got another error as below :
Failed to find Platform SDK with path: platforms;android-31

Answer (score 1):

I realise that this has already been solved but thought I would add that if using the command line tools (sdkmanager) then you need to install `platform-tools` before as a separate command (see below)

```bash
sdkmanager 'platform-tools'
sdkmanager 'platforms;android-33'
sdkmanager 'build-tools;33.0.2'
```

instead of this:

```bash
# this did not work for me
sdkmanager 'platform-tools' 'platforms;android-33' 'build-tools;33.0.2'
```

Hope this helps :)